# Slope of a points in a Circumference

Tags: derivatives

I need to compute the slope (m) of the nine points of a circumference divided in equal parts.  But a circumference is not a function.

I make a Geometric approach but I am not satisfied with it.

Do anyone know how to solve it analytically.

[image]

Comment: That should be $\tan \frac{2k\pi}{9}$, $0\le k\le 8$.

Comment: Parametrize your shape, here a circle, as in $x=r\cos t, y=r\sin t$ and then differentiate that set of equations.

Comment: I can do the differentiation there. But,  I do not know how to Parametrize the shape... I am in my first course of calculus in my first year.  Can  you help me understand the parametrization process?  Where can I have more information?

Comment: I am not sure why you are not satisfied with a geometric approach. It is much more suitable for this problem.

Comment: It is only because this problem is a part of something else.  I am trying to solve it in a formal way.  I need to make it a computable process. If  knowing this you have an opinion I will be very glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the equation of a circle, you can get $y^2=r^2-x^2 \implies y=\pm \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. Now you can use implicit differentiation. It involves using the chain rule in order to differentiate. This is a technique taught in Calculus I, so hopefully you know it.

Check this link out as well- it is exactly what you are doing: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/implicitdiffdirectory/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the equation for a circle, placed at the origin with a radius $ r $: $ x^2+y^2=r^2 $. Solve for $y$, making it the function of $ x $: $y (x)=\pm \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. Now differentiate  with respect to $ x $ and plug in the $ x $-values of the points in question into the expression you got.

Comment: Ok.  But, can I make a differentiation on this?  I don't know how to do it.  I am in my first calculus course. (1st year)

Comment: Take a look at the edits I've made.